# Getting a symbol from a string without it being replaced by its value?

Tags: evaluation, string-manipulation, hold, symbols

Consider the following code running on a fresh Mathematica session with no symbols defined:

```
p[s_String] := Protect[s];
p["x"]
```

This doesn't do anything because there is no symbol named `x` yet, so no symbols match the string pattern `"x"`. No problem, we can resolve this by using `Symbol`:

```
p[s_String] := Protect[Symbol[s]];
p["x"]
```

This doesn't work either, since Protect has the attribute `HoldAll`. So we can use `Evaluate`:

```
p[s_String] := Protect[Evaluate[Symbol[s]]];
p["x"]
```

Great! Now it works. Except... If the symbol we want to protect **does** already exist, then it won't work:

```
y = 1;
p[s_String] := Protect[Evaluate[Symbol[s]]];
p["y"]
```

This will execute `Protect[1]` because `Symbol["y"]` evaluates to `1`. How can one write a function `p` which protects a symbol, **given via a string**, whether or not it already exists?

Thanks.

EDIT: A solution was given in the comments:

```
p[s_String] := Protect @@ ToExpression[s, StandardForm, Hold];
```

However, now I have another similar issue. I would like to find out if s is a proper symbol, so that e.g. `p["1"]` or `p["a b"]` will return an error message. So I tried the same trick with `Head`:

```
p[s_String] := 
  If[Head @@ ToExpression[s, StandardForm, Hold] === Symbol, 
   Protect @@ ToExpression[s, StandardForm, Hold], 
   Print[s, " is not a symbol!"]];
```

This works only if the symbol was not defined previously. For example, if I type `x = 1` and then `p["x"]` I will get `x is not a symbol` because its `Head` is `Integer`. So again, it's the same problem as above: How can I look at the symbol itself without it being replaced by its value?

Comment: What if you just did `p[s_String] := If[MemberQ[Names[s], s], Protect[s]]`

Comment: `Protect @@ ToExpression[s, StandardForm, Hold]`?

Comment: @flinty: But then it won't be protected if it doesn't already exist. I want to protect that symbol from future modifications whether or not it already exists.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thanks, I think that works!

Comment: I now have a similar problem, for which this trick doesn't work. Please see my edit. Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand the problem?: You want to check if the expression from string `s` is a symbol, even though `Protect` checks that for you? What's wrong with letting `Protect` do that work for you?

Comment: ``p[s_String] := With[{symb = ToExpression[s, StandardForm, Hold]},
   If[Developer`HoldSymbolQ @@ symb,
    Protect @@ symb,
    Print[s, " is not a symbol!"]
    ]
   ];``?

Comment: @MichaelE2: This code is just a minimal working example. My actual code is much more complicated and involves a lot more than just `Protect`. Thanks, this code seems to work! But what exactly is ``Developer`HoldSymbolQ``? Is there any documentation for it? Google returns 7 results and none of them explain anything about it. How do people know about this module in the first place?

Comment: The ``Developer` `` and ``Internal` `` contexts have minimal, if any, documentation. If any, it is limited to a usage message and can be found with `? cmd`. Those contexts, and some others, contain many useful functions. Technically, they are subject to change, elimination, etc., but some commands have been around a long time. People know about them from WRI Tech. conferences, share what they find out here, sometimes developers share their knowledge here. Some have code that can be inspected, so people have figured out what they do.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. I am hesitant to use ``Developer`HoldSymbolQ`` in my code, since as you say, this function may change or stop working at any point, and presumably without notice (as it is not documented, there will be no documentation of any changes either). However, I found an easier solution: simply use `Check` to pick up the message sent by `Protect` when the string is not a symbol, and not evaluate the rest of the code in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution to my problem:

```
p[s_String] := 
  Quiet[Check[Protect @@ ToExpression[s, StandardForm, Hold], 
    Print[s, " is not a symbol!"], Protect::pssl]];
```

This solution simply lets `Protect` "do the work for me" (as suggested by @MichaelE2 in the comments). In my actual code, there is much more that happens after calling `Protect`, but I only continue the evaluation if `Protect` was successful.